# Python SQLite TypeError

Tags: python, sqlite

```
from sqlite3 import *

def insert_record(Who, Invented):

    connection = connect(database = "activity.db")

    internet = connection.cursor()

    list = "INSERT INTO Information VALUES((Alexander_Graham, Phone))"

    internet.execute(list)

    rows_inserted = internet.rowcount

    connection.commit()

    internet.close()
    connection.close()

#GUI interface
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()

the_button3 = Button(window, text='Record', command = insert_record).grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=100,pady=5)
window.mainloop()
```

Alright, so what I'm trying to do is when I press the Record button, the values for Information (it have 2 fields called Who and Invented, respectively) in activity.db will add a record Alexander_Graham and Phone.

*activity.db is already premade in the same folder as the code

But instead I get this error:
TypeError: insert_record() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

How do I fix it?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: My bad. I fixed the indentation already.

Answer (score 0):

insert record is a function that takes two required arguments, which you didn't pass values in for.

```
command = insert_record
```

A good example of this in action is the following test sequence:

```
In [1]: def func(one,two):
   ...:     return one+two
   ...: 

In [2]: func()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    --
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-2-08a2da4138f6> in <module>()
----> 1 func()

TypeError: func() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

In [3]: func(1,3)
Out[3]: 4
```

In this function, it fails in the same was as your tk app.  You need to provide a function that has default values, or handle it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

When you press button then tkinter runs function `insert_record()` always without any arguments.

You have to define function without arguments too.

```
def insert_record():
```

Or with with default values ie.

```
def insert_record(Who=None, Invented=None):
```

Or you have to assign function with arguments - you can do it using `lambda`

```
command=lambda:inser_record("Thomas Edison", "Bulb")
```

Comment: Ah, I see. It worked now. Thanks for the explanation.